# split div in two taking all available vertical space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to split a div in two side by side divs. I know that has several examples here, but I already searched and not found one that permit that the divs take all available space in vertical, without any content.

Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/kpDDM/3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776367/css-making-a-div-consume-all-available-space

Comment: You spelt 'class' wrong on the right div.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set a percentage height to your divs, their parent element must have a specific height. In this case it appears you want it based on the viewport height. To achieve this, every ancestor div must have a height of 100%:

```
*, html, body, .parent {
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kpDDM/6/

Answer (score 3):

Add `&nbsp;` within your div tags.  Because they're 100% rather than fixed pixels, they need something inside to make them visible.

If you want to make the div tags 100% of the page, then you need to state the page is 100% (so the div tags understand what 100% is).

`* { height:100%; }`

Changing the body and html tags to 100% is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your `parent` divider takes a %height even though it's parent container, `body`, does not have an explicit height amount. This infers that your `parent` divider overrides with `height:auto` instead, leaving you without the height you wish.

You'll need to declare a fixed height for `parent` if you wish for this to work. Modern browsers today do not support default explicit height amounts for the parent `body`.

Thus, you'll need to make sure you explicitly define your `html` and `body` dividers heights like so:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Enjoy and good luck!