# Make middle div use up all height and left after placing top and bottom elements in a div

Tags: html, css

I have the same question with a slight change

[Make div (height) occupy parent remaining height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225912/make-div-height-occupy-parent-remaining-height)

Here is a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/zf0fvgk0/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="up">Text<br />Text<br />Text<br /></div>
    <div id="middle">Text<br />Text<br />Text<br /></div>
    <div id="down">Text<br />Text<br />Text<br /></div>
</div>
```

How do I make the middle one occupy all the empty height in the div left by up and down?

note: my container, up and down's height can change, so I dont want to hardcode a pixel value

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776367/css-making-a-div-consume-all-available-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a flexbox layout, you could change the `display` of the container element to `flex`.

Then add `flex-direction: column` to the container element so that the children elements flow vertically. In order for the `#middle` element to take up the remaining space, you could increase the `flew-grow` value to something like `1`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/41th3zrn/)

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#middle {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Support for flexboxes can be [found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Add relevant vendor prefixes for additional browser support.

Comment: There is quite poor support of `display: flex`.

Comment: @panther It depends on your definition of *poor support*, it's actually not *that* bad - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox This is a valid option, and in my opinion it's better than using CSS tables. Regardless, I think future users will find this helpful--especially when support improves. Support is already at `88.88%`, which is pretty good.

Comment: If we have eg. e-shop, each 9th customer can't make an order in our shop. I think the support isn't so good. Not when there is an option how to make other way with almost 100% support.

Comment: @panther [Graceful degradation versus progressive enhancement](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement) - in theory, the site *should* still function when it isn't supported. The appearance shouldn't necessarily effect the direct functionality.

Comment: @panther.. even if there is a lesser support than tables, looking at the browser support, this would be the best answer for future readers

Answer (score 1):

use table `display`s values and set full height to the middle one `div`.

```
#container {display: table;}
#container > * {display: table-row}
#middle {height: 100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zf0fvgk0/1/